# Using a variable from one class to another tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Here is the full code for test please run it and tell me if I can store username and password outside the class after destroy the frame

```
import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.title('Instagram Bot')
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Enter Username").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.username = tk.Entry(self,)
        self.username.pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Enter Pssword').pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=10)
        self.password = tk.Entry(self)
        self.password.pack()
        self.password = self.password.get()
        self.username = self.username.get()
        # if(username.get('text') == None or password.get('text') == None):
        #     tk.Button(self, text="Login",
        #           command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()
        # else:
        
        tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne) and login_data()).pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Welcome").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='Some text', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Hashtag_page)).pack()

    def  __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.hastag_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Choice file')
        self.hastag_lbl.pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='browse', command=self.browseFiles_hstg).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Start Bot', command=self.start_hashtag).pack()

        
    
    def browseFiles_hstg(self): 
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                          title = "Select a File", 
                                          filetypes = (("Text files", 
                                                        "*.txt*"), 
                                                       ("all files", 
                                                        "*.*"))) 
        # Change label contents 
        self.hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)


    def start_hashtag(self):
        print(StartPage.username, StartPage.password)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

> > Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1705, in **call**
> > return self.func(*args)   File "scofrlw.py", line 71, in start_hashtag
> > print(StartPage.username, StartPage.password) AttributeError: type object 'StartPage' has no attribute 'username'

Comment: please format your code so we can run it

Comment: The solution depends on how you manage the multiple frames. The comment in `switch_frame` implies you will have destroyed `StartPage` by the time you create `Hashtag_page`. If that's the case, you can't get the value. Please provide a [mcve] we can actually run.

Comment: Can I store the value in global or somewhere outside StartPage I will change to can  run

Comment: You should plan your GUI before coding it, if you haven't. And yes you can store a global variable

Comment: I update the code I try with global but I didn`t get a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, i have been storing the credentials inside the master (SampleApp) which is accessible from your class PageOne aswell.

Alternatively, you may consider storing the credentials in a dict, and passing it
to your PageOne during initialization.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = "I am the MasterAPP"
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.title('Instagram Bot')
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

        self.username = None
        self.password = None

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Enter Username").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.username = tk.Entry(self,)
        self.username.pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Enter Pssword').pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=10)
        self.password = tk.Entry(self)
        self.password.pack()


        tk.Button(self, text="Login",
            command=lambda:
                self.login()
        ).pack()


    def login(self):
        self.save_credentials()
        self.master.switch_frame(PageOne)


    def save_credentials(self):
        self.master.password = self.password.get()
        self.master.username = self.username.get()




class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Welcome").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='Some text', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Hashtag_page)).pack()

    def  __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.hastag_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Choice file')
        self.hastag_lbl.pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='browse', command=self.browseFiles_hstg).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Start Bot', command=self.start_hashtag).pack()



    def browseFiles_hstg(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                        "*.txt*"),
                                                       ("all files",
                                                        "*.*")))
        # Change label contents
        self.hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)


    def start_hashtag(self):
        print(self.master.username, self.master.password)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a dictionary of the username and password, but depending on your GUI, I don't know the best option for you

Make the dictionary

```
dictionary = {}

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
   ...
```

Add values for the username and password.

```
def login_credentials(self):
    dictionary['password'] = self.password.get()
    dictionary['username'] = self.username.get()
```

Then you can just print them

```
def start_hashtag(self):
    print(dictionary['username'],dictionary['password'])
```

Comment: I get empty variable maybe its from tkinter

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

- should not call `self.password = self.password.get()` and `self.username = self.username.get()` just after `self.username` and `self.password` are created because they will be both empty strings and override the references to the two `Entry` widgets.
- `username` and `password` are instance variables of `StartPage`, so they cannot be access by `StartPage.username` and `StartPage.password`
- two `__init__()` function definitions in `PageOne` class
- when switching frame, the previous frame is destroyed.  So `username` and `password` will be destroyed as well and cannot be accessed anymore.

You can use instance of `SampleApp` to store the `username` and `password`, so they can be accessed by its child frames:

```py
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Enter Username").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.username = tk.Entry(self,)
        self.username.pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Enter Pssword').pack(side='top', fill='x', pady=10)
        self.password = tk.Entry(self)
        self.password.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login).pack()

    def login(self):
        # store the username and password in instance of 'SampleApp'
        self.master.username = self.username.get()
        self.master.password = self.password.get()
        # switch to PageOne
        self.master.switch_frame(PageOne)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def  __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.hastag_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Choice file')
        self.hastag_lbl.pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text='browse', command=self.browseFiles_hstg).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Start Bot', command=self.start_hashtag).pack()
    
    def browseFiles_hstg(self): 
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", 
                                              title = "Select a File", 
                                              filetypes = (("Text files", 
                                                            "*.txt*"), 
                                                           ("all files", 
                                                            "*.*"))) 
        # Change label contents
        if filename:
            self.hastag_lbl.configure(text = filename)

    def start_hashtag(self):
        # get username and password from instance of SampleApp
        print(self.master.username, self.master.password)
```